# Input text reads "undefined" in Flash Actionscript 2.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm trying to create a simple game where the 
user can "talk" with the character on screen. However, when I tried the code I was using, the else statement was always triggered, no matter is the password was correct or not. When I couldn't figure out why, I learned that the output was always "undefined." I'm hardly experienced with Flash in general, so the mistake could be simple. I am positive all instance names are written and spelled the same way as in the code.

**Code:**

```
stop();

sendb.onRelease = function(){

    if (textbox.text == "no") {

        gotoAndStop(2);

    } else {

        gotoAndStop(3);

    }

}
```

Where :

- sendb : the submit button
- textbox : the input textbox where the response is typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are using a multiline text field that's why you will get never `textbox.text == "no"`. To verify that, try this with an empty multiline text input :

```
trace(textbox.text.length);     // gives : 1
```

Why you will get always `1` even when your text input is "empty" ?

Simply because, there is a `newline` character (Carriage return or "\r") which is inserted automatically at the end of the text.

So in your case, If you want use a multiline text field, you can do :

```
if (txt.text.substr(0, 2) == "no") {

    gotoAndStop(2);

} else {

     gotoAndStop(3);

}
```

Or use just a single line text field and your code will work fine.

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure *textbox* is in the accessible scope of your code. That means it is in the same frame on the main timeline in which you write your code, and it is at the *root* level of the main stage.